# Combinar columnas de una matriz

Tags: java, matriz

Tengo una matrizuno, la cual puede tener cualquier dimensión, necesito imprimir todas las diferentes submatrices cuadradas que la matrizA tenga, teniendo en cuenta el número de filas que posee.
A continuación un ejemplo.

```
Elementos de la matrizA:
1   2   -1   0   0
2   1   0   -1   0
1   1   0   0   -1
```

Los resultados que se necesitan son:

```
Combinación 1:
1   2   -1   
2   1    0   
1   1    0 

Combinación 2:
1   2    0   
2   1    -1   
1   1    0
```

Y así sucesivamente hasta lograr todas las combinaciones, lo que hice hasta el momento es cargar la matriz e iniciar a hacer la impresión de columnas con respecto al número de filas que posee.

```
int[][] matrizuno = {{1, 2, -1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, -1}};
System.out.println("Las matrices que hay son: ");
for (int f = 0; f < matrizuno[f].length; f++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < matrizuno.length; c++) {
        System.out.print(matrizuno[f][c]);
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
 }
```

Pero así como lo planteé solo me imprime las 3 primeras columnas de cada fila, alguno sabría como pordría realizar la iteración que menciono?, he intentado de diferentees formas entre ellas  agregando un contador que me incremente el número de columnas al final de la iteración pero también me arroja un error en el arreglo, me encuentro algo confundido por como podría obtener el resultado mencionado, agradecería cualquier aporte para solucionar mi inconveniente, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si las sub matrices son del mismo tamaño y siempre se toman los primeros dos elementos de la sub matriz el siguiente código debe funcionar:

```
        int[][] matrizuno = {{1, 2, -1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, -1}};
        
        // la siguiente posición de la matriz
        int siguiente = 2;
        // el límite es la longitud máxima de la submatriz
        int limite = matrizuno[0].length;

        // repetir mientras la siguiente posición no haya alcanzado la longitud
        // de la submatriz
        while (siguiente < limite) {
            
            // recorrer la matriz principal
            for (int i = 0; i < matrizuno.length; i++) {
                
                // tomar los primeros dos elementos de la matriz principal
                // e imprimirlos
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                    System.out.print(matrizuno[i][j] + " ");
                }
                // imprimir el elemento de la submatriz en la posición siguiente
                System.out.print(matrizuno[i][siguiente] + "\n");
            }
            // incrementar la posición siguiente
            siguiente++;
        }
```